# Define the settlement date of Libor. Where to get them

Tags: libor

I am having problems understanding what day is the settlement date for a libor rate, and how to find it for a given rate, e.g., Overnight, 1-Week, etc?

Comment: Overnight = tomorrow, 1-Week = 1 week from today?

Comment: In addition Holidays must be taken into account https://www.theice.com/publicdocs/LIBOR_Holiday_Calendar_2017.pdf

Comment: Overnight, 1-Week, etc is the ___maturity___, not the settlement. I don't know how/when these things settle, and I am assuming it is not T+2, etc.

Comment: Which currency? Some of them settle T+0, some are T+2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A libor that fixes on $t_f$ starts on $t_s$ and end on $t_e$, with typically 
$t_s$ = $t_f + \text{lag}$ with following adjustment, and $t_e = t_s + \text{tenor}$ with following or modified following adjustment depending on daily, weekly or monthly tenor. Also the EOM rule usually applies.

Lag and adjustments will depend on the currency and may be based on several calendars. 
For instance in the case of Euribor 
$t_s$ = $t_f + 2$ target days, $t_e = t_s + \text{tenor}$ adjusted following or modified following target

Or in the case of Libor USD $t_s$ = $t_f + 2$ London days adjusted following London+New York, $t_e = t_s + \text{tenor}$ adjusted following or modified following London+New York.

You will find most Libor conventions here: 
https://developers.opengamma.com/quantitative-research/Interest-Rate-Instruments-and-Market-Conventions.pdf